# Text not aligned with itself within cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

### Example

Image of text behaving weirdly
[image]

### Explanation

The baseline of text inside the cells is not aligned relative when it is rotated 45 degrees anticlockwise. Some letters are above or lower their expected graphical place in the text string.

- The same symptoms occurs with text rotated the other way.
- Text alignment whether horizontally or vertically has no effect on the behaviour of said text.
- Rotated cells that have text pushed to a new line also have weirdly aligned text.

While this is an more aesthetic than functionality concern, I'd like to know the cause of this behaviour.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The text in the image looks fine, how do you want it to appear?

Comment: @spikey_richie If you draw a straight line under the rotated text, you'll see most of the letters are not on the same baseline.

Comment: I have no idea why, but I can confirm I see the same phenomenon here: W10 Pro 64-bit; Excel 365 32-bit and various fonts -- both fixed and proportional

Comment: Do you see the same problem on a printout or PDF of your worksheet?